# Question about serializing a Location subclass in order to write them to a file

Tags: android

As I understand things, in order to save an ArrayList of objects to a file using ObjectOutputStream, the Objects in the ArrayList need to implement Serializable.

I'm trying to save an ArrayList of Locations to a file, so I extend Location into a class that does that (and nothing else).  So I have a class that looks like...

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import android.location.Location;

public class MyLocation extends Location implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7599200646859829149L;

public MyLocation(Location l) {
    super(l);
    
}

}
```

But now, in my location listener it crashes at

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        locat = (MyLocation)loc;
```

I suppose it doesn't like the typecasting?  I dunno, I'm a little confused.  Sorry if this is obvious, I haven't been doing this long.

The serialVersionUID line was generated by Eclipse using "add generated serial version ID"

#### Update:

Like I said before, I'm trying to read/write an arraylist of Locations to/from a file.  When I write my data to a file, I don't get any exceptions, but I do get an exception when I try to read it.  Basically I have a class that extends ArrayList (because I needed it to be parseable for Listview purposes...

```
public class LocationList extends ArrayList<MyLocation> implements Parcelable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

it's a LocationList named waypoints that I write to a file.  This seems to work fine (ie it doesn't throw an exception or crash)...

```
FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream os;
        os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject(waypoints);   // <-- writeObject doesn't throw an exception.
        os.close();
```

but when I try to read that file, I get an IO exception...

```
FileInputStream fis;
    
    try {
        fis = context.openFileInput(fileName);
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        is.readObject();   // <--this is the line that throws an IO exception
        is.close();
```

This is probably a naive attempt at saving/loading a moderately complicated object.  Any advice?

NOTE: I simplified it a bit.  Originally the offending line was

```
waypoints = (LocationList) is.readObject();
```

but I was worried that I had a similar problem with the casting as above so i took it out temporarily.  Anyway, readObject() throws an exception without the typecast there, so I guess that's not my current problem.

Comment: Well the entire object tree needs to be serializable, not just the top level node. So everything in Location would need to be serializable.

Answer (score 1):

Is the location object that is passed to you a MyLocation instance? My guess would be no, since the system is providing it. Just because you extend a class doesn't mean you can cast from the super type.  What you really want to do is:

```
   locat = new MyLocation(loc);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I'm not sure right now why I cant cast from the super type, but I'll read up on it.

Comment: It's can be somewhat confusing, you can read up some more here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Looks like a good resource, thanks.  I have a followup problem regarding the reading/writing of the arraylist of MyLocations, but stackoverflow wont let me "answer my own question" for a few more hours since I'm new here.  Since it's related to the title of this thread I dont want to start another, I'll post it here tomorrow morning.